# Can not squeeze dim[2], expected a dimension of 1, got 2

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, object-detection

I'm trying to create a CNN that takes some head images as input and gives output 4 keypoints (in coordinates format (x,y)).

Input Images are in format (1000,1000,1) and keypoints are in format [[0.1,0.2][0.3,0.4][0.5,0.6][0.6,0.7]].

When I Run the program, I get this error:

```
Node: 'cond/remove_squeezable_dimensions/cond/Squeeze'
Can not squeeze dim[2], expected a dimension of 1, got 2
     [[{{node cond/remove_squeezable_dimensions/cond/Squeeze}}, {{node mean_squared_error/cond/remove_squeezable_dimensions/cond/Squeeze}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_1432]
```

Here's the code (at the momento is in a dummy stage):

```
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)

# for image,keypoints in dataset.as_numpy_iterator():
#     print("Image shape:",image.shape)


input_shape = (1000,1000,1)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(3, (3,3), strides = (1,1), padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))


model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(10,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(4))
model.summary()

#opt = Adam(learning_rate=0.0005,decay=1e-3)

model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer='adam',metrics='mae')

# Train the model for 1 epoch using a dataset
print("Fit on Dataset")
history = model.fit(dataset, epochs=1, batch_size=batch_size)
```

Printing Input shape with commented code we get this output:

```
Image shape: (5, 1000, 1000, 1)
Image shape: (5, 1000, 1000, 1)
Image shape: (5, 1000, 1000, 1)
Image shape: (5, 1000, 1000, 1)
Image shape: (5, 1000, 1000, 1)
Image shape: (5, 1000, 1000, 1)
Image shape: (5, 1000, 1000, 1)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the output of running # for image,keypoints in dataset.as_numpy_iterator():
#     print("Image shape:",image.shape)

Comment: Please share the data preprocessing part of your code to understand and resolve the issue.